# How to create tree view (like expandable list ) in flex builder for mobile?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, tree, builder, expandablelistview

I want to create a tree view (expandable list ) in flex 4.5 builder mobile,Is it possible for web projects in flex builder for web ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-1c32bcb9124deadc3e9-8000.html ) but I did not get any luck for mobile.

Comment: I am not able to find answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Spark Tree component](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/spark-tree/). It is based in Spark List and inherits all the mobile-specific logic from it.